# isinstance based custom validator in pydantic for custom classes from third party libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

In my custom package for work, I want to validate inputs using `pydantic`. However, most of my functions take inputs that are not of native types, but instances of classes from other libraries, e.g. `pandas.DataFrame` or `sqlalchemy.Engine`. Mentioning these as type hints and adding `pydantic.validate_arguments` decorator fails.

Let's suppose the input of my function should be of type `CustomClass` from library `CustomPackage`.

```py
import CustomPackage
import pydantic


@pydantic.validate_arguments
def custom_function(custom_argument: CustomPackage.CustomClass) -> None:
    pass
```

This will lead to the following error:

> RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'CustomPackage.CustomClass'>, see arbitrary_types_allowed in Config

To solve this, I can use `@pydantic.validate_arguments(config={"arbitrary_types_allowed": True})` instead, which will allow anything. This is not my intention, so I followed the [custom type section in documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/#classes-with-__get_validators__), and created this:

```py
import collections.abc
import typing

import CustomPackage


class CustomClassWithValidator(CustomPackage.CustomClass):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls: typing.Type["CustomClassWithValidator"]) -> collections.abc.Iterable[collections.abc.Callable]:
        yield cls.validate_custom_class

    @classmethod
    def validate_custom_class(cls: typing.Type["CustomClassWithValidator"], passed_value: typing.Any) -> CustomPackage.CustomClass:
        if isinstance(passed_value, CustomPackage.CustomClass):
            return passed_value

        raise ValueError
```

After this, the following works fine:

```py
@pydantic.validate_arguments
def custom_function(custom_argument: CustomClassWithValidator) -> None:
    pass
```

But I have quite a few of third party dependencies, and each have lots of custom classes which I am using. Creating almost identical class for every single one of them as above will work, but that does not seem optimal. Is there any functionality in `pydantic` to make this less repetitive?

Comment: Crossposted on https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/5906#discussion-5239445.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any built-in Pydantic way in version 1 to do this *other* than adding the `__get_validators__` generator function to your types you already found.

I think one of the main reasons for this is that *usually* you want field types to not just be validated as being of the correct type, but also *parsed* or serialized/deserialized because in most areas, where Pydantic is applied, you either instantiate Pydantic models from Python primitives or objects of built-in types or even from JSON text.

So Pydantic not only provides default validators for the most common types, but also sensible and somewhat flexible initialization and (de-)serialization functions for those types.

The implication then is that if you want to use some custom/foreign type, *you* are responsible for telling Pydantic how to instantiate and validate it.

### Workarounds

#### Option A: Simple mix-in

If all you want is to have a blanket "dumb" validator simply checking `isinstance` for any given type, you can just re-write what you already have as an agnostic mix-in class to minimize repetition:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator
from typing import Any, Self


class ValidatorMixin:
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Any]]:
        yield cls.__validate__

    @classmethod
    def __validate__(cls, v: object) -> Self:
        if isinstance(v, cls):
            return v
        raise TypeError(f"Not an instance of {cls.__name__}: {v}")
```

Then you can simply inherit from that with together with any specific class you want:

```py
from pydantic import validate_arguments

# ... import ValidatorMixin


class Bar:  # from foo
    ...

class Eggs:  # from spam
    ...


class MyBar(ValidatorMixin, Bar):
    pass

class MyEggs(ValidatorMixin, Eggs):
    pass


@validate_arguments
def f(bar: MyBar, eggs: MyEggs) -> None:
    print(bar, eggs)
```

Now the problem with that is your arguments now must be of the types `MyBar` and `MyEggs` and cannot be just of type `Bar` and `Eggs`.

#### Option B: Generic mix-in

To allow specifying which class exactly to validate against, while keeping repetition to a minimum, we need to get creative. An approach I would suggest is making the `ValidatorMixin` generic in terms of what class to check against. There is a bit of magic you can do to then automatically extract the type argument passed to it and validate against that: (see here for details)

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar, get_args, get_origin

T = TypeVar("T")


class ValidatorMixin(Generic[T]):
    _type_arg: type[T] | None = None

    @classmethod
    def _get_type_arg(cls) -> type[T]:
        if cls._type_arg is not None:
            return cls._type_arg
        raise AttributeError(f"{cls.__name__} is generic; type arg unspecified")

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for base in cls.__orig_bases__:  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
            origin = get_origin(base)
            if origin is None or not issubclass(origin, ValidatorMixin):
                continue
            type_arg = get_args(base)[0]
            if not isinstance(type_arg, TypeVar):
                cls._type_arg = type_arg
                return

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Any]]:
        yield cls.__validate__

    @classmethod
    def __validate__(cls, v: object) -> T:
        if isinstance(v, cls._get_type_arg()):
            return v
        raise TypeError(f"Not an instance of {cls.__name__}: {v}")
```

Now you can use it like this:

```py
from pydantic import validate_arguments

# ... import ValidatorMixin


class Bar:  # from foo
    ...


class Eggs:  # from spam
    ...


class MyClass(ValidatorMixin[Eggs], Bar, Eggs):
    pass


@validate_arguments
def f(obj: MyClass) -> None:
    print(obj)


f(Eggs())
```

As you can see, this now also allows you to use multiple inheritance, yet still specify exactly what to validate against. That `f` call in the last line will therefore pass validation.

There is however still one flaw with this. Static type checkers will complain about that call because `Eggs` is not a subtype of `MyClass` (it is the other way around), so that call would be seen as an error.

#### Option C: Monkey-patch the class itself

If that bothers you, the only other reasonable alternative in my opinion would be to just monkey-patch the classes you want to use instead of subclassing and mixing. Something like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterable, Iterator
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


def add_validation(
    cls: type[T],
    validators: Iterable[Callable[..., Any]] = (),
    force_patch: bool = False,
) -> type[T]:
    method_name = "__get_validators__"
    if not force_patch and hasattr(cls, method_name):
        raise AttributeError(f"{cls.__name__} already has `{method_name}`")
    if not validators:
        def __validate__(v: object) -> T:
            if isinstance(v, cls):
                return v
            raise TypeError(f"Not an instance of {cls.__name__}: {v}")
        validators = (__validate__, )

    def __get_validators__(_cls: type) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Any]]:
        yield from validators
    setattr(cls, method_name, classmethod(__get_validators__))
    return cls
```

Now this can be used both as a simple function for monkey-patching some third-party class and as a decorator for your own classes.

(You are also free to add other validation functions via the optional `validators` argument.)

Usage:

```py
from pydantic import validate_arguments

# ... import add_validation


class Bar:  # from foo
    ...


add_validation(Bar)


@add_validation
class SomeCustomClass:
    ...


@validate_arguments
def f(bar: Bar, obj: SomeCustomClass) -> None:
    print(bar, obj)


f(Bar(), SomeCustomClass())
```

If you want, you can make a more sophisticated version of that decorator allowing usage with or without additional arguments:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterable, Iterator
from typing import Any, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")


@overload
def add_validation(
    cls: None = None,
    *,
    validators: Iterable[Callable[..., Any]] = (),
    force_patch: bool = False,
) -> Callable[[type[T]], type[T]]: ...


@overload
def add_validation(cls: type[T]) -> type[T]: ...


def add_validation(
    cls: type[T] | None = None,
    *,
    validators: Iterable[Callable[..., Any]] = (),
    force_patch: bool = False,
) -> type[T] | Callable[[type[T]], type[T]]:
    def decorator(cls_: type[T]) -> type[T]:
        nonlocal validators
        method_name = "__get_validators__"
        if not force_patch and hasattr(cls_, method_name):
            raise AttributeError(f"{cls_.__name__} already has `{method_name}`")
        if not validators:
            def __validate__(v: object) -> T:
                if isinstance(v, cls_):
                    return v
                raise TypeError(f"Not an instance of {cls_.__name__}: {v}")
            validators = (__validate__, )

        def __get_validators__(_cls: type) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Any]]:
            yield from validators
        setattr(cls_, method_name, classmethod(__get_validators__))
        return cls_
    return decorator if cls is None else decorator(cls)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. I think I'll go with the 3rd approach for now, and when V2 is out, will switch to `InstanceOf` as suggested in the crossposting link.